Undefined Behaviour as the std::wstring is not properly constructed. What is the best fix for legacy code?
Found strange std::wstring problem (or bug VS 2022 + strange size & capacity 0 from missing construction).
It is in large legacy C/C++ project.

Minimal (shortest) reproducible example
std::wstring &hell = *(std::wstring*)calloc(sizeof(std::wstring), 1);
hell = L"a"; // hell contains quite random Unicode wchar then

hell are members of struct T and there are dynamic arrays of T + they are realloc-ed often.
Shortened original code examples:
class T { public:
    _tstring yyyName;   
    int a, b, c, d;

};
T *y = (T*)calloc(no, sizeof(T));
T *y = (T*)realloc(y, NumOfParams * sizeof(T));


Problem should be default _Small_string_capacity == 7 and missing construction.
There is probably no point analysing "bug" details.

Quickest and easiest fix, but maybe not the best one:
template<class T>
class lazyPtr {
public:
    lazyPtr() {
        _member = new T();
    };
    operator T&() {
        if (!_member) _member = new T(); // construct missing string
        return *_member;
    };
    T operator =(const T right) {
        if (!_member) _member = new T(); // construct missing string
        *_member = right;
        return *_member;
    }
    ~lazyPtr() {
        delete _member;
    };

private:
    T *_member;
};

lazyPtr<std::wstring> fix = *(lazyPtr<std::wstring>*) // intended nonsense
    calloc(sizeof(lazyPtr<std::wstring>), 1); // create uninitialized string again
fix = L"y";


Are there better options except large refactor or C++ workaround like template shown here ?
Would only solution be refactor the whole project ? Replace malloc/zeromem/calloc/free/memcpy by new/delete/(copy/default)constructors and use vectors instead of T struct arrays ?


Current solution - minimal string like class:
class PtrString {
public:
    PtrString& operator = (const PtrString& rhs);
    PtrString& operator = (const _tstring& rhs);
    PtrString& operator = (const _TCHAR* cstr);
    ~PtrString();
    operator const _TCHAR* () const {
        return m_data;
    }
    const _TCHAR* c_str() const {
        if (m_data) return m_data;
        else {
            static const _TCHAR* empty = _T("");
            return empty;
        }
    }
    operator _tstring () const {
        return m_data;
    }
    inline size_t length() const {
        return m_data ? _tcslen(m_data) : 0;
    }


private:
    _TCHAR *m_data;
};


PtrString& PtrString::operator = (const PtrString& rhs) {
    return this->operator=(rhs.m_data);
}
PtrString& PtrString::operator = (const _tstring& rhs) {
    if (m_data)
        delete m_data;
    const size_t fullSize = rhs.length() + 1;
    m_data = new TCHAR[fullSize];
    memcpy(m_data, rhs.c_str(), fullSize * sizeof(TCHAR));


    return *this;
}


PtrString& PtrString::operator = (const _TCHAR* cstr) {
    if (m_data)
        delete m_data;
    size_t fullSize = _tcslen(cstr);
    if (fullSize++) {
        m_data = new TCHAR[fullSize];
        memcpy(m_data, cstr, fullSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
    }


    return *this;
}


PtrString::~PtrString() {
    if (m_data) {
        delete m_data;
        m_data = nullptr;
    }
}

It was next to impossible to refactor legacy code, looks like only reliable fix would be to start from scratch.
PtrString member;

In the struct did the job similar quite compatible with original C spaghetti.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There is no such thing as best fix, there is only the best fix in specific circumstances, of which we know very little.
I see two ways out of your situation: either refactor the code to use idiomatic C++ (which does not entail using new and delete everywhere — we prefer smart pointers these days), or refactor it using idiomatic C and use a C compiler to build it. Which option is better in your specific circumstances I cannot tell.
I can see no point in the template above, or owning pointers to C++ strings or containers in general. Just use std::wstring hell = L"a";.

It helps a lot in case you need to easily track content/updates to find errors, etc. and do not need much changes of existing spaghetti... But used also stripped POC https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/3108ca565920f2c1bb97e5ddb39e7e172629f6ae/cString.h
